# my rss reader code get blank page not getting Feed

Tags: android, rss, blogs, feed, rss-reader

Please  any one can help me, this is a code get it from a website and modify it to be used in android studio system, and it's work fine but the page is white so i don't know where is the problem?!

this the link you can download it from here:

https://github.com/nerdability/AndroidRssReader

Comment: Welcome to SO. I am afraid the default site set on this sample app is down. (http://nerdability.com/) So unless you reset the reader to read another website, it is not going to work. :) Try change the default value to a different Website and see if it works. Good luck

Comment: i change it to reuters news feed, but the same problem :(

Comment: Sorry to hear that. However, it is not possible for us to look at the sample code and figure out where your implementation has mistake. Try debug mode and see if it has error message.

Comment: no any error message on the logcat except one like more frames are skipped , i didn't see the message of "Caused by "
 you can download the modified one (android studio project) 
from this link: [http://www.4shared.com/rar/xXdX87MVba/RssReader.html?]
please i need the help :(